# Mysql/Doctrine - Check if month is between 2 dates

Tags: mysql, doctrine

I have a table let's say **road_trip** with a **startDate** and **endDate** columns.

I would like to make a query that can search if a month or multiple months (gonna be an array) lies between startDate and endDate.

For exemple if startDate = "2020-05-21" and endDate = "2025-05-22"
For given month = 5 (corresponding to May), we should have some result.

But for this exemple: startDate = "2020-06-21" and endDate = "2020-07-22"
For given month = 5 (corresponding to May), we should not have any result since month don't lie between date.

I don't know how to write my efficient query.

*I started with the native function MONTH but it doesn't work properly since i need to check the year if for example the year of startDate is 2020 and for endDate we have 2025. The month will automatically between them but if years are the same, it may not lie between the dates.*

Thank you all

Comment: make month(yourdate) and year(yourdate) then with AND

Comment: I can't year my date because it's not a date it's just a month, it could be 5 (May) or 11 (November). And given a month, i would like to know if this month lies between a range of 2 dates stored in my table

Comment: extract year from year(curdate()) and add it to your date , that will be your date + current year

Answer (score 0):

This works under MySQL 8 and Mariadb 10.3 and will not be fast

> ```
> CREATe TABLE road_trip (startDate Date,endDate  Date)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO road_trip  VALUES("2020-06-21", "2020-07-22" ),("2020-04-21", "2020-07-22" )
> ```

> ```
> create fUNCTION findnemo( _startdate date ,_enddate date, _amonth int)
> RETURNS INT
> DETERMINISTIC
> BEGIN
> WITH RECURSIVE t as (
>     select  _startdate as dt
>   UNION
>     SELECT DATE_ADD(t.dt, INTERVAL 1 DAY) FROM t WHERE DATE_ADD(t.dt, INTERVAL 1 DAY) <= _enddate
> )
> select SUM(MONTH(dt) = _amonth) into @count FROM t;
> RETURN @count > 0;
> END
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM road_trip WHERE findnemo(startDate,endDate,5)  > 0
> ```
>
> ```
> startDate  | endDate   
> :--------- | :---------
> 2020-04-21 | 2020-07-22
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fff8da75b9538c5ec190dcc875891692)*